# How to merge video and audio without re-encoding?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, mp4, codec

There are 2 files:

```
General
Complete name                            : D:\TEMP\videofile.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom (avc1/mp42/dash)
File size                                : 5.93 GiB
Duration                                 : 1 h 49 min
Overall bit rate                         : 7 776 kb/s

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 4 frames
Format settings, GOP                     : M=4, N=50
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 1 h 49 min
Bit rate                                 : 7 773 kb/s
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.150
Stream size                              : 5.93 GiB (100%)
Title                                    : Anvato eDASH 2.1
Codec configuration box                  : avcC

Text #1
ID                                       : 1-CC1
Format                                   : EIA-608
Muxing mode                              : SCTE 128 / DTVCC Transport
Muxing mode, more info                   : Muxed in Video #1
Duration                                 : 1 h 49 min
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Stream size                              : 0.00 Byte (0%)
CaptionServiceName                       : CC1

Text #2
ID                                       : 1-CC4
Format                                   : EIA-608
Muxing mode                              : SCTE 128 / DTVCC Transport
Muxing mode, more info                   : Muxed in Video #1
Duration                                 : 1 h 49 min
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Stream size                              : 0.00 Byte (0%)
CaptionServiceName                       : CC4
```

and

Audiofile Mediainfo: https://pastebin.com/Sn0rBAXg (moved to Pastebin, because SOF did not allow "so much code" in a question).

When I open them in [PotPlayer](https://potplayer.daum.net) - I can watch the video (though, it opens quite long, up to 40 seconds). But I want to merge these 2 files into 1, I tried using ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i videofile.mp4 -i audiofile.mp4 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy -y output.mp4
```

And it produces video only 33 minutes long. How to merge these video and audio without re-encoding?

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: @Gyan sure. Raw (57 MB): https://dropmefiles.com/RMrSn and zipped (3 MB): https://dropmefiles.com/akvx2

Answer (score 0):

**The concat demuxer will merge video(s) & audio(s) without re-encoding.**

Create a text file name `frames.txt` in the following format:

```
file '/path/to/v1.mp4'
file '/path/to/v2.mp4'
file '/path/to/v3.mp4'
```

Then use below command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i frames.txt -c copy out.mp4
```

The files will be stream copied in the order they appear in the frames.txt into the out.mp4.

Note: the "copy codec" is blazing fast.